# Can't delete file after it gets written

Tags: java, file, inputstream, delete-file

I'll put my code first:

```
@Post
public Representation post(InputStream zip) throws Throwable {
    createFile(zip, "C:/temp");
    return new StringRepresentation("File uploaded");
}    

public void createFilee(InputStream zipStream, uploadedFileLocation) throws Exception {
    try {
        writeToFile(zipStream, uploadedFileLocation);
        FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw e;
        }
}


private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        uploadedInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I send a file to my server, it cannot get deleted.  When using `FileUtils.forceDelete()`, it says that it cannot delete the file.  I can delete the file manually while the server is still running after it tries to delete the file with file utils.  Why can't it just delete it itself?! any ideas?  Thanks

EDIT:  Could the issue be that the `InputStream` from the POST is alive until the POST returns?  So, even when I call to delete the file, the stream is still kept alive by the POST?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe permission issues on file?

Comment: I've noticed sometimes when closing files and then immediately trying to access them can cause weird behavior sometimes on certain machines, such as an anti-virus opens the file for a millesecond to do something once you have closed it.  I know it's a bad long term solution, but see if adding a sleep before attempting to delete solves the problem.

Comment: Could the issue be that the InputStream from the POST is alive until the POST returns? So, even when I call to delete the file, the stream is still kept alive by the POST? Is this even possible?

Comment: @StephenD why is out being instantiated twice? is it a typo?

Comment: Why are you deleting the file immediately after creating it?

Comment: I accept a zip file as the file, then i extract it.  then delete the zip, keeping the unzipped output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my limited windows experience it can be one of the two things

I would check 
1) THe anti-virus software is trying to scan the file
2) Some kind of indexer (System or custom) is trying to index the file.

you can use a tool like processExplorer to see which process holding up the file descriptor.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Could the issue be that the InputStream from the POST is alive until the POST returns? So, even when I call to delete the file, the stream is still kept alive by the POST? Is this even possible?